# How to create one large dataframe of specific excel information using python pandas from a list of excel paths

Tags: python, python-2.7

Perhaps an easy fix.
I am looking to extract specific information from many of the same style of excel workbooks within a directory and concatenate the specific information all in into one workbook (while changing the format). I have completed every part of this task except for successfully creating one big dataframe of n columns from the different workbooks(proportional to the number of xlsx files read). Each of the read workbooks has only one sheet ['Sheet1']. Does this sound like I am taking the right approach? I am currently using a for loop to gather this data.

Upon much research online (Github, youtube, stackoverflow), others say to make one big dataframe, then concatenate. I have tried to use a for loop to create this dataframe; however, I have not seen users "piece together" bits of data to form a dataframe the way I have. I don't believe this should hinder the operation. I realize I am not appending or concatenating, just not sure where to go with it.

```
for i in filepaths:           #filepaths is a list of n filepaths`
    df = pd.read_excel(i) #read the excel sheets`
    info = otherslices   #condensed form of added slices from df`
    Final = pd.DataFrame(info)  #expected big dataframe`
```

The expected results should be columns directly next to each other (one from each excel sheet respectively)

```
Excel1  Excel2    ->  Excel(n)
info1a  info1b
info2a  info2b
info3a  info3b
...     ...
```

What I currently get when using "print(Final)" in loop is

```
Excel1
info1a
info2a
info3a
...
Excel2
info1b
info2b
info3b
...
|
Excel(n)
```

However, the dataframe I get from this loop (when I type "Final") is only
the very last excel workbook's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my own solution to this problem.

```
    Final = pd.DataFrame(index=range(95))    #95 is the number of rows I have for each column
    n=0

    for i in filepaths:           #filepaths is a list of n filepaths 
        df = pd.read_excel(i)     #read the excel sheets`
        info = otherslices         #condensed form of added slices from df`
        Final[n]=pd.DataFrame(info)
        n+=1

    Final = Final.append(Final)  #big dataframe of n columns
    Final
```

Comment: The outcome is exactly as expected from my original post

Comment: Update: "Final = Final.append(Final)" is not needed. this duplicated results

Answer (score 0):

I would create a list of data frames which you append in each loop then after the loop concate the list into a single data frame. So something like this.

```
Final=[]
for i in filepaths:           #filepaths is a list of n filepaths`
    df = pd.read_excel(i) #read the excel sheets`
    info = otherslices   #condensed form of added slices from df`
    Final.append(info)  #expected big dataframe`'
Final=pd.concat(Final)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I gave this a try and have come across the syntax error of pd.concat needing an iterable of pandas objects, not DataFrame. Isn't a Dataframe a pandas object?

Comment: It is. Could you respond with the exact error? Also for more info on combining dataframes this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) is usefull. My guess is that the info variable is not a dataframe. You can comment out the pd.concate line and see what the Final variable is. It should be a list of dataframes

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Edited my code need to change Final=append to Final.append

Comment: "info" for me is a list i created of slices of the dataframe df. Perhaps I should make this a dataframe first?

Comment: Yes convert info into a dataframe

Comment: on "Edited my code..." I understood what you meant =)

Comment: So each DataFrame column I am working with is 94 rows. Info was changed to a dataframe and concatwas commented out. When typing Final.shape outside of the loop the return is (190, 1) as if it is accepting two columns of data (i think?). keep in mind the example I provided has omitted portions of the code I don't think interfere with the looping (but might?).

Comment: How many times do you append info. If it is 190 then the (190,1) makes sense. It is because final is now comprised of 190 dataframes which are in 1 column. Have you tried it again with the concat uncommented?

Comment: In my case, n=10, which is to say, I have 10 different columns of data, each 94 rows. So I am after 10 dataframes (each 94x1). When I attempt to execute the code with Final =pd.concat(Final), I receive the TypeError: error once again.